# Basic Probability example

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there is a box of balls, 30% blue, 15% red, 45% orange and the rest black ( %10)

a) What is the probability that a randomly selected ball is either blue or red

b) What is the probability that a non-black ball is blue ?

For part a)
  `P(A + B) = 30 + 15 = 45%` is what i think, but im not sure if i need to use the

```
           P(A + B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) formula ?
```

for part b)
   The chance of getting a non-black ball is 90%, but how do i get the probability of blue balls knowing this

Any tips or hints when it comes to thinking about these problemss?

Comment: $P(AB)$ is the probability that the ball is both blue and red.  Since the balls are monochrome, that is zero.

Answer (score 1):

When having the number of balls expressed as percentages, its best to use an arbitrary integer to see the relative number of balls you actually have.

So, if the total number of balls is $20$, we have that:

$6$ balls are blue

$3$ balls are red

$9$ balls are orange

$2$ balls are black

So for part (a) we have that either the ball can be blue or red.

So here we have to add probabilities.

So, the probability of choosing a red ball is $\frac{3}{20}$, and the probability of choosing a blue ball is $\frac{6}{20}$

Adding, we get the total probability to be $\frac{9}{20}$

For part (b)., we have to know the number of balls that **are not** black. This is $20 - 2 = 18$ balls.

Of those $18$, we find that $6$ are blue.

Therefore, the probability of choosing a blue ball is $\frac{6}{18} = \frac{1}{3}$

Hope this helped. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: @KarelMacek, what you say makes no sense. Indeed, one-third of all the non-black balls are blue.

Answer (score 0):

a) This is $30\%+15\%=\boxed{45\%}=\boxed{\frac9{20}}.$

b) $1-10\%=90\%$ of the balls are possible. Therefore, the probability is $\frac{30\%}{90\%}=\frac{30}{90}=\boxed{\frac13}.$

Answer (score 0):

> For part a)
>     `P(A + B) = 30 + 15 = 45%` is what i think, but im not sure if i need to use the
>
> ```
>           P(A + B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) formula ?
> ```

You did use that.   P(AB) is the probability that the ball selected is both blue and red; which is *zero* since the balls were monochrome.   We say $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events (or mutually exclusive event), meaning their intersection is a null set.

> for part b)
>      The chance of getting a non-black ball is 90%, but how do i get the probability of blue balls knowing this

Use the definition of conditional probability.

You seek the probrobability that the ball is one from the $30\%$ of balls that are blue (event $A$), when given that it is one from the $90\%$ of balls that are not black (event $D^\complement$).

$$P(A\mid D^\complement)=\dfrac{P(A \cdot D^\complement)}{P(D^\complement)}=\dfrac {30\%}{90\%}=\dfrac 13$$

(since all blue balls are in fact not black: $A \cdot D^\complement=A$.)